# Style checkboxes in mat-select with multiple options

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I have a mat-select that I'm using with the `multiple` option (see [this example from docs](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vnmjrvorkjk?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)).
I want to style the color of checkboxes when they are selected (by default it's blue).
So from this:

[image]

I need to get this:

[image]

but I don't know which css selector/rule I should use.
Normally for checkboxes I would use this:

```
/deep/.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #A5C73C;
}
```

but the options are not seen as checkboxes.

**HTML**:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following CSS appears to work, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqcpqz?file=app/select-multiple-example.css):

```
::ng-deep .mat-primary .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
    color: unset;
}

::ng-deep .mat-option-pseudo-checkbox.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked {
    background-color: #A5C73C;
}
```

Comment: The select component actually internally uses psuedo checkboxes when multiple mode is enabled which are intended for _"decorative purposes and CSS-only"_ (see https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13945#issuecomment-435568941), as compared to the normal checkbox component. (This should be added to explain what the `mat-pseudo-checkbox-*` classes actually do.